# Unable to download a file from AWS with Java

Tags: java, xml, amazon-web-services, io

I'm currently trying to write a Java program to download a gzipped file stored on a remote server.

The code I have been using works on some URLs, such as:

ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/geo/DATA/SOFT/by_series/GSE10/GSE10_family.soft.gz

But it throws an IOException when trying to access an AWS URL, such as:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/.... (I can't link the file due to confidentiality reasons, but it is a valid .gz file)

The problem being (I think) that the content type of the URL that works is of type 'octet-stream', which is fine, but the AWS URL is 'xml'.

Is there a way to access the octet-stream?

Here is the code I was using:

```
try{

        URL url = new URL("ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/geo/DATA/SOFT/by_series/GSE10/GSE10_family.soft.gz");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("GSE10_family.soft.gz");

        int i = 0;
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[3000000];
        while ((i = in.read(bytesIn)) >= 0) {
            out.write(bytesIn, 0, i);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
}
catch (MalformedURLException e){

}
catch (IOException e){

}
```

And here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:       https://s3.amazonaws.com/...
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1673)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1671)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1244)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at DataProcessor.downloadAndUnzip(DataProcessor.java:79)
at DataProcessor.processFile(DataProcessor.java:34)
at Test.main(Test.java:25)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://s3.amazonaws.com/...
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2678)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(URLConnection.java:522)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentType(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:406)
at DataProcessor.downloadAndUnzip(DataProcessor.java:78)
```

Comment: Can you share the Exception you're getting?

Comment: It's throwing an IOException when the URL is changed to the AWS URL.

Comment: Please **show** that exception - theres a message given that would help with the fixing. Oh and even if the content type is XML, it should download that fine just as well (you just might not be able to open it...)

Comment: Apologies, I've posted it in an edit.

Comment: Ah. `java.io.FileNotFoundException`   you're sure that URL is correct and can be called from a (not logged in or something!) browser? It's basically a 404 you get there.

Comment: Yes. Copying and pasting the URL directly into my browser (not logged in) immediately downloads the file. From another post it was suggested to add


`httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");`
`httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");`

But it still isn't working.

Comment: Still ... your browser might remember stuff. If the file is to be kept confindential, then maybe there is some kind of protection in place - or could anyone download just given he/she has the correct link? As a second way you could try HttpClient instead of URLConnection and see where that gets you

Comment: While working on a similar problem, I found that `FileNotFoundException` will be triggered by any 4xx error. I used `HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` to see the actual HTTP status, which was 400 in my case.